# Highcharts polar spider with Min and Max for each y-axis

Tags: highcharts, spider-chart

I want to create a Spider Graph with Each axis having a different scale.

Example : 
First axis Min : 0 and Max : 1 
Second axis Min : 0 and Max : 100 
Third axis Min : 0 and Max : 1 
Fourth axis Min : 0 and Max : 5

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the min and the max for each yAxis and assign the correct axis to each series:

```
  yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    max : 1,
    angle: 0
  }, {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    angle: 90
  },{
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    angle: 180
  }],
  series: [{
    data: [.8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3, .2, .1],
    yAxis: 0
  }, {

    data: [11,22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88],
    yAxis: 1
  }, {

    data: [1, 4, 2, .7, 3, .6, 4, .5],
    yAxis: 2
  }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8kawx9m/1/